# MOSS 2007 - Site Usage Statistics Not Generating

Tags: 2007, site-usage

We are having an issue with one of our single server MOSS 2007 setups. Site usage statistics are enabled within central admin console (and SSP), as well as on the site collection in question, but no statistics are being displayed in the front end. It just says the standard "No data is available for this report. Usage analysis might have been enabled only recently, or there might have been insufficient usage to result in any values for the report."

The log files are being generated (to the default location with the WSS_ADMIN_WPG permissions etc) without problem and when the timer jobs run at night, they are processing the files as the ampersand is being appended to each line. Each days log files contains over 150,000 entries for a many sites and it has been enabled for a long time so I don't believe it to be an issue with not enough data being processed.

All the related timer jobs are running and don't appear to have any issues (no entries in error logs etc).

I have tried a number of things to get these statistics working including:

- Disable / Re-enable Statistics
- Server Reboot
- Timer Service Reset
- Configuration Cache Reset

I have also looked into the SSP database (using NOLOCK of course!) and I can see that there hasn't been any new entries in the ANLHistoricalUsage for over 200 day ID increments (comparing the latest entry in the ANLDay table for today's ID).

Can anyone please provide any advice on why SharePoint wouldn't be processing the log files into the database? My next plan would be to set up SQL profiler on the database around the time that timer jobs fire to monitor but if anyone has any advice, that would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,
Poolybit